# Implementing list and trying few methods in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here I want to create a List (score[]) where I can add, delete, display and sort the score values accordingly. Well while sorting I'm getting an Error which is mention after the code:

```
score=[];
choice=None;
while choice!=0:
print "1. Dislplay the score\n";
print "2. Add the score\n";
print "3. Delete a score\n";
print "4. Sort the scores\n";
choice=raw_input("enter the choice\n");
if choice=="1":
    print score;
elif choice=="2":
    print "enter the no. of scores u want to update";
    add=int(raw_input("enter the scores u know:\n"));
    i=0;
    while i<add:
        scores=int(raw_input("enter the score\n"));
        score.append(scores);
        i+=1;
elif choice=="3":
    print "enter the score you want to delete or remove:\n";
    del_score=int(raw_input("delete score:\n"));
    if del_score in score:
        score.remove(del_score);
    else:
        print "the required score is not found in the list";
elif choice=="4":
    print "now its time to sort the scores in list\n";
    sorted_score=score.sort();
    sorted_sore=sorted_score.reverse();
    print sorted_score;
else:
    print "you have entered a wrong choice mate ";
```

The Error is -

```
Error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shijith\Desktop\python exer\listmethodsscore.py", line 29, in <module>
    sorted_score=sorted_score.reverse();
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reverse'
```

Comment: Site note: all those semicolons at the end can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> The **sort()** and **reverse()** methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

So, `.sort()` and `.reverse()` alters given list in place so do not return any value. You should replace the following:

```
sorted_score=score.sort()
sorted_sore=sorted_score.reverse()
```

with this

```
score.sort(reverse=True)
```

to get it worked.

Alternatively, if you want your `score` list untouched, you should use `sorted()` over `sort()` which will create a new list and keep the existing one as is.

```
reversed_scores = sorted(score, reverse=True)
```

Here is a great [article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) regarding how sorting works in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to first sort and the reverse the sorted_sore list
But you are storing the result of score.sort() in sorted_score which doesnt makes sense as **.sort() method is in place so only doing score.sort() will suffice.**

Also if you want to reverse it you can either use **reversed()** method or **reverse slicing method like [::-1]**

PS:Also **.reverse() method is inplace** so assigning it to variable doesnt makes sense

Comment: thanks it worked !! :) and thanks for the idea of reversing the list via slicing !

Answer (score 1):

`score.sort()` doesn't return anything. It merely sort the array without returning it. So, your sorting should be:

```
score.sort();
score.reverse();
print score;
```

So, the easy way to understand it is when the `sort()` method is called, the reversed array is assigned to the `score` variable instead of being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Because sort() is a method that sorts in-place the list, it does not return anything. So if you write in the Python interpreter:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.sort()
b is None
```

you will get:

```
True
```

After doing a.sort(), 'a' is sorted.

In your example:

```
sorted_score=score.sort();
sorted_sore=sorted_score.reverse();
```

what happened was that 'sorted_score' became None and then you tried something like None.reverse() which generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

the .sort() method of lists sorts the list in place, while sorted() creates a new list.

So

```
sorted_score = score.sort();
```

assigns None to the variable.

Therefore when you reverse it

```
sorted_sore = sorted_score.reverse()
```

you get an error, correctly.

BTW you have a typo there (sorted_sore) as well as unnecessary semicolons all over the code